# C# WebBrowser - Get elements that load later on even after the page has completed

Tags: c#, .net, automation

I am fairly new to programming so pardon my stupidity if any. I am using a WebBrowser on WindowsForm to navigate over to YT's upload section

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/upload");
```

The problem is that I want to click on 'publish' after the video has finished uploading. How would I do that? How would the browser know that the uploading has finished?

```
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
     Application.DoEvents();
}
```

The above code doesn't help either because the Document has already loaded completed. And there are facebook and twitter content, where page keeps loading more and more content via js with ajax as you scroll. So how'd you know and target that new content which appears later on?

Comment: whats your aspnet template. Is it aspnet web form or aspnet mvc or aspnet mvc core or another

Comment: I am working on WindowsForms

Comment: Why don't you use Youtube API instead of doing this webbrowser tricks https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Comment: I'm fairly new and thus fond working API's difficult.

Comment: Never rely on a web page's structure to create a program around it, even less if the page isn't yours, whenever there's a change in the page's structure your program will stop working. Better take your time and learn how to interact with the api, it will end in a better program and you will also learn something new.